# Calculate standard error for breeding population from summary statistics for male and female sub-groups.

Tags: standard-error, descriptive-statistics

I need to obtain a mean and standard error for energetics values for a bird population for use in a Monte Carlo model. The following data were obtained from the literature:

```
males: mean = 3792.000 kJ/day, SD = 723.290, SE = 273.378, n = 7
females: mean = 3054.333 kJ/day, SD = 13.051, SE = 7.535, n = 3
```

I calculated the energetic demand for an average individual in the population (defined as 0.5 male/female pairs) by adding the means of the sexes to estimate energy consumption per pair, then dividing by 2.

However, it isn’t clear to me how to determine the standard error for the above mean. I can approximate it via simulation using R:

```
pv<-rnorm(1000000, 3792, 273.378) ##simulated means for males
bv<-rnorm(1000000, 3054.333, 7.535) ##simulated means for females
sd((pv+bv)/2) ##standard error of combined population for 0.5 pairs (i.e. one individual)
```

...~136.7. However, it seems to me there must be a more straightforward way. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mathematically there are straightforward ways--I'm sure people will describe some in answers.  I just wanted to point out that the values for the females appear to be hyper-confident: it is implausible that any population of birds, no matter how specialized, will exhibit values that consistent.  I also wonder why it would be relevant to use a standard error to run a stochastic model.  In some specialized circumstances an SE could be used in a meaningful way, but for most applications wouldn't you want to model the *population* rather than *the uncertainty in your estimate of the mean*?

Comment: @whuber, thanks kindly for the comments. The lit values for females are indeed unexpectedly similar, but they are the best available data (though I certainly wish I had more!). As far as using the SE rather than SD,  I’m modelling the total energy used by an entire colonial seabird colony during a simulated breeding season. The simplest way to do this seems to be to multiply the mean energy requirement per individual by number of individuals in the colony. So the uncertainty in the estimate of the mean individual energy requirement (SE) is actually what I’m after. Cheers.

Comment: OK--but I would worry about (a) correlations among energy requirements within a colony, (b) correlations (possibly negative!) among breeding pairs, and (c) the tiny size of the sample. You could replace the SE for the females by that of the males (or maybe use a relative SE), to be conservative. (That might depend on the biological explanation.  *E.g.,* if the females sit on nests and the males forage, the males *should* have a larger SD.)  Also, to be conservative, you might entertain the possibility that the energy requirements might be highly correlated within a colony.

Comment: @ whuber, thanks, and comments well taken. I ended up using 10% of the average energetic demand per pair as a conservative SE, which works out to about twice the calculated value. I'm not sure I understand your point about correlations within a colony completely, but energy demands are indeed likely to vary across colonies and years. The "padded" SE you recommended should help account for both this likely variation, and the uncertainty in the mean of the sampled population. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question (after some gentle help from a colleague). Variance for independent random variables is additive, so add the squares of the SEs for each sex (which is another way of saying add the variances of the sampling distribution for each sex) and take the square root to get the SE per breeding pair. Divide by two for the SE per 0.5 pair.

$$SE = \frac{\sqrt{273.378^2 + 7.535^2}}{2}$$

$$ SE = 136.7$$